# Jquery add click event on table row, but do not invoke it when pressing specific element in that row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table, and I have added a click event to all of its rows.
In each row, I have an input field that when clicking on it I don't want it to fire the row's click event, but it does.

I tried something like:

```
$("#copyFromDocsTable > tbody > tr:not(.copyDocQty)").live("click" ,function(){...});
```

where `copyFromDocsTable` is the name of the table and `copyDocQty` is the class name which I gave to all of the inputs.

Comment: please post your html markup as well

Answer (score 1):

Add an event handcler to the input field and call .stopPropagation() on the event.

```
$('.copyDocQty').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

If you are building the table in javascript, you would use event delegation instead:

```
$('.myRow').on('click', '.copyDocQty', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I am using an example classname and input selector which you will have to adjust.

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution that works, but will try yours also :)

Answer (score 0):

After playing with it I found something that works

```
    $("#copyFromDocsTable > tbody > tr").live("click" ,function(e){
    if (!$(e.target).closest('.copyDocQty').length) {...}});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add another event handler on input field and stop propagation.

Check this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myTable").on("click", function(evt){
   alert('table clicked!');
  })
  $(".my-input","#myTable").on("click", function(evt){
   evt.stopPropagation();
  })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/11064/